# Need help to generate view where data comes from many models

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I need some suggestions about how to generates a view where data comes from 3/4 models.
I have attached an image where data is coming from 3 models. I have done that in web form using 3 different gridviews and binding different data sources.

But now I have to do the same in MVC 3 and finding it difficult.
I would really appreciate if anyone can give me some guide line about how to generate such view.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, pass all your models through as properties of the 'Model' object, and then use partial views to render each section, passing through the particular model they use.

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName", this.Model.SubModel)
```

Or, use child actions, and have a separate action method for bit of the page. i.e. add this to your parent view:

```
@Html.Action("ActionName", "ViewName")
```

The advantage with the latter is you can using caching policies ([OutputCache] attribute on your action) for parts of your page which are more static that other parts.

Answer (score 2):

I would define a Model containing 3 Properties

```
public class CompositeModel
{
   public MenuModel Menu {get; set;}
   public OrderModel Order {get; set;}
   public RestaurantModel Restaurant {get; set;}
}
```

And pass this model to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tuple() to return more than one recordsets (models) to a view. Tuple() is a new feature in C# 4.0. View this article about Tuple().

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/11/working-with-tuple-in-c-40.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use partialViews, and render them on page, or you can pass as much data as you want through Viewbag. Example:

```
ViewBag.Model1 = yourModel1;
ViewBag.SomeData = someOtherData;.....
```

And then in view you yust use it:

```
@ViewBag.Model1
```

You could even get data through ajax calls, and by the looks of your sample I would take that approach and use jquery templates to render view.